# getting Numeric value '08/14/2023' is not recognized error on snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a date column on my table. mistakely we have some wrong dates like 15/15/2023. so i want to delete that date from the table. there are the distinct dates i have in mm:DD:yyyy format.

```
RECONN_DATE
10/23/2023
11/23/2023
11/27/2023
11/15/2023
15/15/2023
11/24/2023
13/15/2023
14/15/2023
```

i am trying this query to delete the wrong dates like 14/15/2023 because we don't have 14 month

```
delete from reconn_output_1 where reconn_date = 14/12/2023
```

but i am getting an error

Comment: If you have "invalid" dates in that column, then the column is surely not specifically a "date" data-type - therefore you likely just need to wrap your 14/12/2023 in quotes (so that it's just treated as text).  But, as you haven't actually included the specific error message that you are receiving, it's difficult to know exactly what the underlying problem is ....

Comment: @Craig if i wrap in quotes i am getting this error : invalid identifier '"13/12/2023"' (line 76)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the rows do not parse you can use this fact via the TRY_TO_DATE to get null values, and then delete rows with null values:

```
select $1 as RECONN_DATE
    ,try_to_date(RECONN_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as as_date
    ,as_date is null as the_rows_to_delete
from values
    ('10/23/2023'),
    ('11/23/2023'),
    ('11/27/2023'),
    ('11/15/2023'),
    ('15/15/2023'),
    ('11/24/2023'),
    ('13/15/2023'),
    ('14/15/2023');
```

[image]

thus:

```
delete from table_name
where try_to_date(RECONN_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy') is null
```

should do the trick. It will delete rows where RECONN_DATE is also start to start with. but that can be worked around with more logic.